# Connecting script In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to use one 3rd party library and in their documentation, they showed method to connect website, but here I see script tag. I am using React Native, how I can use this code below in my application. I have no idea.

Code:
[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

That is a script for a website, not a react native application, so it won't work out of the box. You will need to find a specific library that implements the functionality you want for react native.